# tragen trug getragen but beauftragen beauftragte beauftragt

Tags: verb, irregular-verb

Could a native German speaker explain to me why the following verbs are irregular

```
tragen trug getragen
betragen betrug betragen
auftragen trug auf aufgetragen
beitragen trug bei beigetragen
```

but magically the following one

```
beauftragen beauftragte beauftragt
```

is regular?

Comment: It's not really a question for a native speaker but maybe for a linguist. As a native speaker I never ever thought of this issue before. And as a person who learnt (or try to learn) some language I can only tell you to accept it as it is.
But yes, it is not logical. At least not to me.

Comment: +1, cuz I never thought I would find this interesting. This site is a pest :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I respectfully disagree.  There is logic; the verb *beauftragen* is constructed from the noun *Auftrag* with the prefix *be-*, and the noun element *Auftrag* is not affected by the variation of the verb.

Similarly: *beeinflussen* from *Einfluss*, *beinhalten* from *Inhalt*, *beanspruchen* from *Anspruch*.

Comment: +1, sounds very logical. But couldn´t it be just by accident? Is the "be-" prefix really responsible?

Comment: What about "belassen", for example. It would acknowledge the rule, right? Not constructed from a noun -> follows the "lassen" verb irregularity, right?

Comment: "belassen" does not have a noun in its stem like beAUFTRAGen, beINHALTen, beEINFLUSSen.

Comment: What about "Betrag"? The past of the verb "betragen" is "betrug".

Comment: @Sentry I do not think "Betrag" and betragen apply to the rule *abacus* has given. The prefix "be" should not come from the noun. In your case it has to be "bebetragen" and such verb does not exist.

Comment: @Sentry Betrag itself is a noun. but there exist no verb to it. "betragen" is an adjective, thus the past form is regular

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for a *logical* answer, you're out of luck :)

But in general, it's like this: the younger a verb is, the more likely it will be a regular one - which is true for English, too, btw.

You usually can't tell whether a verb is going to be regular or irregular when looking at it for the very first time - you'll just have to memorise the lists, I'm afraid.

Comment: It is a great relief to get a reminder that English native speakers have to learn irregular German verbs just like German native speakers have to learn irregular English verbs :D

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples for this phenomenon, e.g. `schlagen` vs `veranschlagen`, or even two declinations for the *same* verb (but with different meanings), e.g. `hängen` or `schleifen`. As already mentioned, there is no "logic" behind this.